# /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Tags: 14.04, fan, fancontrol

I have tried the solution given here: [Fancontrol under Ubuntu 14.04 – resolving /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed](http://iandw.net/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/):

editing `/etc/default/grub` and replace `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"`. Then

`sudo update-grub` and `reboot`.

But still after the command `sudo pwmconfig`, it shows the same error

```
# pwmconfig revision 6166 (2013-05-01)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

How do I resolve this ?

Output of `sensors`:

```
$sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +71.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +71.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +70.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +61.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

**System Details:**

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit

Lenovo Z560

**Note:**

The same problem occurred before with `12.04 64bit` in the same system.

Comment: lm-sensors is not detecting any fans so pwmconfig is not going to do anything. Adding acpi_enforce_resources=lax to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT is to correct a specific problem, and there is no evidence yet that you have this problem so put it back the way it was.

After you have reverted your etc/default/grub, sudo update-grub and reboot.

Then sudo sensors-detect and accept all the default answers using return and paste the entire dialog into your question. You can use paste.ubuntu.com